# Can I bottle ale after 2 weeks in keg?

Tags: bottling, kegging, secondary-fermentation, sediment

I've primary fermented my Woodfordes Admiral Reserve for 4 days, kegged with 3oz if sugar and it's now it's been in there a week. I don't want sediment in my beer. Can I bottle it after 2 weeks in the keg?

Thanks in advance.

Kenny.

Comment: Just an aside to your question, 4 days is a bit soon to be doing anything with your beer.  Have you tasted it?

Answer (score 4):

If its carbed up in the keg you'll still need a CO2 source to push the beer out of the keg and into bottles.  Otherwise you'll be losing carbonation as you go.  Bottling from the keg isn't that hard.  You can use a [beer gun](http://www.blichmannengineering.com/beergun/beergun.html) from blichmann.  I have also jammed a piece of tubing into the opening of a cobra tap.  The tubing reaches to the base of a bottle and that works pretty well at minimizing foam.

Seeing how you put the beer in the keg only after 4 days, I'd suspect that there is a lot of sediment in the keg.  You might want to rack the beer to a new keg to get it off the sediment.  Or pull out the dip tube from the keg and trim a few inches off the end so you don't pick up the sediment when you finally do push the beer out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wait for the sediment to fall to the bottom then just run your beer until it is clean? It should only take a few cups of beer to remove the sediment. Just make sure the keg rests for a few days before running off the sediment to ensure it all settles.

You shouldn't have a problem bottling after it has been in the keg, but you will need to add a small bit of sugar to let it prime in the bottle.  Cap it and let it sit for a week before opening!  Any sooner and it won't have enough carbonation.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for exploding bottles.  After only 4 days of fermentation, it's possible that there are a lot of unfermentables left in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a keg, why not go the extra step and add CO2 to carbonate in the keg?  Then you can bottle or use growlers for friends or to take a couple beers with you and not be dependent on bottling.